# testing library jest - test style upon table cell click

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have an html table which has onclick handlers for each cell (td), so that when it clicks the cell, it changes it's background color.

```
const handleRowCellClick = jest.fn()

const tableRows = container.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('table tbody tr')
expect(tableRows[0]).toHaveStyle('background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)')

// click data cell
fireEvent.click(within(tableRows[0]).getByRole('cell'))
expect(handleRowCellClick).toHaveBeenCalled()

// expect background to change to selected colour
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(within(tableRows[0]).getByRole('cell')).toHaveStyle(
     'background-color: rgb(229, 255, 255)',
   )
  })
```

the functionality works as expected but the unit tests, last expectation is failing to detect the colour change, after a cell click.

what is the best way to test this change of styles?
FYI I have used the expectation with and without `await waitFor(()` but both failed to detect the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the fire event inside the act

```
act(() => {
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("AddIcon"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `async` for the `await`. you can add it after the test description

example:

```
test('when click on a recored', async() => {

  const tableRows = container.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('table tbody tr')
  expect(tableRows[0]).toHaveStyle('background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)')
.
.
.
```